# How to create a new column, matching values with headers from a different dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

Seems too simple to fail: I have a dataframe with names and values, and I want to create a new column that will contain labels that interpret the names. Those labels exist in a separate dataframe. So I'm trying to use `dplyr`'s `mutate()` and `pull()`, but get an error.

### Data

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df <-
  tribble(~ animal, ~ weight,
          "dog", 20,
          "cat", 10)

##   animal weight
##   <chr>   <dbl>
## 1 dog        20
## 2 cat        10
```

#### I have another dataframe that contains labels for each animal

```r
labels_tbl <-
  tribble(~ dog, ~ cat,
          "a domesticated carnivore of the family Canidae", "a domestic species of small carnivorous mammal")

##   dog                                            cat                                           
##   <chr>                                          <chr>                                         
## 1 a domesticated carnivore of the family Canidae a domestic species of small carnivorous mammal
```

And I know that I can use `pull()` to extract values from columns:

```r
pull(.data = labels_tbl, var = dog)

## [1] "a domesticated carnivore of the family Canidae"
```

So I was trying to use `mutate` and `pull`:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(label = pull(.data = labels_tbl, var = animal))
```

But then got this error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `label`.
> x Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
> x Subscript `var` has size 2 but must be size 1.

Which quite frankly I don't understand.

### Desired output

```r
  animal weight label                                         
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>                                         
1 dog        20 a domesticated carnivore of the family Canidae
2 cat        10 a domestic species of small carnivorous mammal
```

I'll be grateful with any solution, but am trying to wrap my head about what's wrong with this specific method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
labels_tbl %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
select('animal' = name, 'label' = value) %>% inner_join(df)
Joining, by = "animal"
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  animal label                                          weight
  <chr>  <chr>                                           <dbl>
1 dog    a domesticated carnivore of the family Canidae     20
2 cat    a domestic species of small carnivorous mammal     10
```

Comment: btw, `pivot_longer` has `values_to` and `names_to` arguments, which helps to save one line of renaming.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
output <- labels_tbl %>%
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "animal") %>%
  rename(label = V1) %>%
  right_join(., df, by = "animal")
```

which gives:

```
  animal                                          label weight
1    dog a domesticated carnivore of the family Canidae     20
2    cat a domestic species of small carnivorous mammal     10
```

So what i'm doing is transposing your label lookup file, do some polisihing and then right_join with your original df. You could play around a bit more with the column order if you need a particular one, but it gets the job done.